# Modify streaming interval in Collector for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-collector

I'm using ESRI Collector App. I'm tracking location. Is there a way to modify the ESRI location tracking layer for it to use an interval under 5 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

In the Collector App go Setting/Collection Settings/Streaming Interval and there is a sliding scale that ranges from 1 second to 1 minute.